# Dropdown box in ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I was using a combinations of images , textfields, tableviews etc as shown below for developing  my ipad application  to get  the functionality of a dropdown box with auto filling and other features which i used after  modifying  from a template. But there are some problems with event handling. Can anyone suggest me a better library or provide me with similar classes  for implementing  dropdownbox. Thanks in Advance.  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below link for this purpose, this provides a source code for this control.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mlpautocompletetextfield